# Compiling C file which includes other header files

Tags: c, gcc, g++

I am trying to compile a file Mv.c like - `g++ microtime.c Mv.c`
It gives an error - `v.c:2:10: fatal error: microtime.h: No such file or directory 2 | #include <microtime.h>`

 My current directory has both microtime.h and microtime.c and Mv.c includes microtime.h
I am not sure how to go about compiling it. 
Since my main program Mv.c is using microtime.h do I need to compile microtime.c first and pass it as an argument to g++? 
I got it compiled by using the command `g++ -I. Mv.c microtime.o`
where microtime.o I generated using `g++ -c microtime.c` 
I am not sure why this command works and why we need to specify the extra -I. option when I have already created the compiled object file microtime.o

Comment: When you say `#include <…>` it means “look for this in include directories. You want to say`#include “…”` which means “include this file from this path” and with just file name it’s the current directory

Answer (score 1):

If you write `#include <microtime.h>`, the compiler uses its list of system directories to look for the header file. By the option `-I` you add a directory to this list, and the compiler is happy.

To include project-local header files, use `#include "microtime.h"`.

Read the chapter ["Directory Options"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html) in GCC's documentation to learn more.